# Index out of range for list even though the index/length should be updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Each time I remove a data point in my list it obviously decreases the index by 1, however I am unsure as to why the index is out of range since the length of the list should be updating. Please help, thank you!
My code:

```
def highest_degree():
    degree_options = ["Less than Bachelor’s", "Bachelor's degree", "Master's degree", "Doctorate degree", "Professional degree"]
    degree_lst = random.choices(degree_options, weights=(1, 30, 55, 10, 4), k=400)
    data_lst = make_list()
    data_stage_one = []
    x = 0
    found = False

    while len(degree_lst) != 0:
        if degree_lst[0] != data_lst[x][1]:
            x += 1

        if degree_lst[0] == data_lst[x][1]:
            data_stage_one.append(data_lst[x])
            data_lst.remove(data_lst[x])
            found = True
        
        if x > len(data_lst) - 1:
            x = 0

        if found == True:
            degree_lst = degree_lst[1:]
            found = False

    return data_stage_one

print(highest_degree())
```

Here is my error message:

```
line 36, in highest_degree if degree_lst[0] == data_lst[x][1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You check that `if x > len(data_lst) - 1:` and set `x = 0` if that is `True`. But at the start of the next loop, if the first if condition is true, you increase `x` by 1. So if `len(data_lst)` equals 1, `x` may now be 1 and you'll get an `IndexError`.

Comment: The best/easiest way to solve this is simply to litter your code with print statements, and step through it (you can juse `input()` to wait for <enter> before things continue if you like); alternatively, use a debugger. Debugging these kind of loops with small input sets usually show quickly where things go wrong.

Comment: Note that we don't know what `make_lst` does and returns, so we don't know what type of list `data_lst` is. If items in its second dimension can be of length 1, you'll also get an `IndexError`, because you use `data_lst[x][1]`.

Comment: When you execute the while loop ```while len(degree_lst) != 0:``` with the value of len(degree_ist) == 1.  What happens to your logic?